# Need help in creating a view with following data

Tags: sql, view

I have a table like

```
A | All,
B | X,
C | Y,
D | Z
```

so I have to create a view replacing all with rest of the values in column.
So my desired output will be

```
A | X,
A | Y,
A | Z,
B | X,
C | Y,
D | Z
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT col2
        FROM   Yourtable
        WHERE  col2 <> 'All') a
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT col1
                   FROM   Yourtable
                   WHERE  col2 = 'All') b
UNION ALL
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM   Yourtable
WHERE  col2 <> 'All'
```